# How can I make the outer circles

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to make the display feature for my app, but I am having a hard time making these outer circles, any input is appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to draw using coordinates.
You can set the ratio using `MediaQuery.of(context).size`.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              top: 200,
              left: 80,
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(128.0),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Positioned(
              top: 225,
              left: 105,
              child: Container(
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(128.0),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou Sir, but i am trying to have these half circles

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: const LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.white,Colors.white, Colors.red, Colors.red, Colors.white,Colors.white],
                  transform: GradientRotation(pi / 2),
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(128.0),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 198,
                  height: 198,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(120.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

It leads to this output:

[image: gradient bordered circle]

Answer (score 0):

use **stack** widget and put 2 circle containers with different size as children in stack widget